# Foundation 5 Zurb: alignment issue with large-4

Tags: html, zurb-foundation

I have been looking at this code for an hour and still can't seem to find the issue:
Here is the site http://www.iamcavic.com/simon if you look at the bottom of the page you will see the issue with columns "On Sale", "New Stock", "Sponsor"

**HTML**

```
  <!-- Pro Shop and Sponsor -->
  <article>

    <div class="large-4 columns">
       <!-- Wrap -->
      <div class="outter outter-padding">
        <div class="content">
          <h1>on sale</h1>
          <hr>
          <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
        </div><!-- END content -->
      </div><!-- END outter -->
      <!-- END Wrap -->
    </div>

    <div class="large-4 columns">
       <!-- Wrap -->
      <div class="outter outter-padding">
        <div class="content">
          <h1>new stock</h1>
          <hr>
          <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
        </div><!-- END content -->
      </div><!-- END outter -->
      <!-- END Wrap -->
    </div>

    <div class="large-4 columns">
      <!-- Wrap -->
      <div class="outter outter-padding">
        <div class="content sponsor">
          <h1>sponsor</h1>
          <hr>
          <a href="http://www.wilson.com/en-us/tennis/"><img src="img/wilson-large.jpg" alt="large wilson logo"/></a>
        </div><!-- END content -->
      </div><!-- END outter -->
      <!-- END Wrap -->
    </div>

  </article><!-- END Pro Shop and Sponsor -->
```

Is it possible that there is an issue with their large-4 columns setup or am I missing something. No errors are showing in fire bug and I even tested it with W3 validation. Thanks in advance, my guess is on issue with Foundation :(

Comment: Can you describe the issue or what is the expected result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add clear element before your bottom content:

```
<div style="clear:both"></div>
<article>
  ...
</div>
```

Comment: I should have tried that before I asked the question :).. Silly error, thanks for help Slawa

Answer (score 0):

Since you are not using rows, next column is placed as the normal flow. Your previous content row containing RECOGNITION has height more than that of PLAYER ARCHIVE. This causes next column added to be placed after RECOGNITION and below PLAYER ARCHIVE.

I don't know if it's a problem with the Foundation or not. But you can solve this problem by adding padding-bottom to previous large-4 column containing content PLAYER ARCHIVE.

Padding bottom of 35px looked good.

```
element.style {
   padding-bottom: 35px;
}
```